# How to turn on the debugger mode in eclipse through script/command

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a web application deployed on tomcat through maven.I have done setup for running it in debugging mode and also setup eclipse.it is working fine.

My only problem is every time I restart my tomcat,I have to go to eclipse to turn on the debugger mode.

Is there any way by which I can turn on debug mode through some script/command along with tomcat starting command so that eclipse debugger mode can be turned on automatically without any manual effort?

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to debugger mode bu using **F11 key**. Use **F8** to resume debugging and **F6** to move one breakpoints to others.